# How can I check collision between two objects and execute a function for only one of the objects?

Tags: python, pygame

I have written a 2D gravity simulation in python - pygame and the issue is when two objects collide. When they collide I wish to remove one of the objects and run a function for the remaining object. However, since object A collides with B and B collides with A, both objects are deleted and the function would run twice, once for each object.

```
circles = []

class Circle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mass = 0
        self.radius = 0

        # r, g, b
        self.colour = [0, 0, 0]
        self.otherCircles = []

        # x, y, mass, dist
        self.centerOfMass = [0, 0, 0, 0]

        # x, y
        self.force = [0, 0]
        self.spe = [0, 0]
        self.pos = [0, 0]

        self.drawCom = True
        self.drawLine = True

    def detect_col(self):
        for circ in self.otherCircles:
            dX = circ.pos[0] - self.pos[0]
            dY = circ.pos[1] - self.pos[1]
            dist = math.sqrt((dX ** 2) + (dY ** 2))

            if dist <= circ.radius + self.radius:

                # This line removes the self object from the list of circles.
                # Both objects are removed since the line runs for both objects
                circles.remove(self)

                # I wish to remove only one of the two objects and run a function for the remaining object

                # Clear otherCircles from all circles in list circles and update list of otherCircles
                for circ2 in circles:
                    circ2.otherCircles.clear()
                self.find_others()
```

Comment: What is `circles` and what is `self.otherCircles`= are this the same list?

Comment: Sorry. `circles` is a global list, not class specific. The `self.otherCircles` are all circles in the `circles` list except itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you do something like this:

```py
for object_a in list_of_objects:
    for object_b in list_of_objects:
        if object_a != object_b:
            # do somthing
```

With this approach each collision is detected twice. If you want to detect each collision once, you have to do something as follows:

```py
for i, object_a in enumerate(list_of_objects):
    for object_b in list_of_objects[i+1:]:
         # do somthing
```

The outer loop goes through all objects. The inner loop only goes through all objects that are successors of the first object.